# Need to display this twitter feed from a website on my website

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to display this twitter feed located here:
http://www.mccabesirishpub.ca/kitchener/
would love if it can be done somehow as an iframe or something equivalent, please give me details with your answer as I am student and doing this to learn stuff, this part of a project we are doing.
Regards!

Comment: try searching for "add twitter feed to website" on a search engine

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do an iframe and reference the objects id in order to display on another site, but unfortunately twitter's widget doesn't have an id that you could use for that.

But the preferred process for making this exact widget is pretty simple. If you login to twitter and go to:
https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/

you can create this exact widget for any public twitter feed.

Twitter then gives you an html embed code that you simply paste in your html where you want it and boom, twitter feed.

Here's an example of a twitter feed I just made for the place you're asking about:
http://jsbin.com/kisetejoca/1/

Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck with your class! ;)

edit:

Did my answer help, or is there something else you need? If so, could you mark it as the correct answer?